# Calculating tvalue using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

As part of an exercise i needed to check whether a given sample's true mean is 1.75 or not by generating tvalue using numpy and compare with the output from scipy.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(seed=42) # make example reproducible
n = 100
x = np.random.normal(loc=1.78, scale=.1, size=n) # the sample is here
tval, pval = stats.ttest_1samp(x, 1.75)

var_x = x.var(ddof=1)
std_x = np.sqrt(var_x)
tval1 = (x.mean() - 1.75)/(std_x*np.sqrt(n))
print("Scipy: ",tval,"\nNumpy: ",tval1)
```

The output from Scipy is   2.1598800019529265,
while output from numpy is 0.021598800019529265

I guess the logic i used is incorrect, Please suggest.

Comment: Alright, let me just remember everything I know about `tvalues` and `ttest_1samp` and so on.

Comment: numpy can calculate the standard deviation for your directly using `np.std(x)` or `x.std()`. No need to go via the variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in the denominator. It should be

```
tval1 = (x.mean() - 1.75)/(std_x / np.sqrt(n))  # (std_x divided by root n)
```

That's why you will find there is a factor of 100 difference ((1/10)/10 = 1/100) between your `Scipy` and `numpy` output.

Here is the [Wiki of Student's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)

---

An example using another sample size:

```
np.random.seed(seed=42)
n = 369
x = np.random.normal(loc=1.78, scale=.1, size=n) # the sample is here
tval, pval = stats.ttest_1samp(x, 1.75)

var_x = x.var(ddof=1)
std_x = np.sqrt(var_x)
tval1 = (x.mean() - 1.75)/(std_x / np.sqrt(n))
print("Scipy: ",tval,"\nNumpy: ",tval1)

# Output:
# Scipy:  6.306500305262841
# Numpy:  6.306500305262841
```